# what is the best way to select features for logisitc regression in Python?

Tags: python

I have a datafram with 18 independent variable and a binary dependent variable.
I want to loop through all possible combinations between 18 variable so it would give me a models where p-value is less than 5% for each variable in the model
I have written a code for that, but when I ahve 18 variable, it takes forever to loop through each combination.

I ahve tried using

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
chi2, f_classif, mutual_info_classif
```

but i'am not sure if this is what i'am looking for

is there another method that would give me a best model with the combination of variable with the p-value less than 5% in a model

Comment: With 18 features to choose from, there are 153 pairs to consider, which isn't all that many; I suspect that if the code you wrote is really going that slowly, you're probably doing something inefficiently. That said, if you want to guess at which two features to consider, you might want to try selecting the features with the highest [mutual information](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html) with the dependent variable.

Comment: In retrospect, my suggested approach might be what you meant when you said that you imported `mutual_info_classif`...

Comment: One reason your code might be running slowly is that you have a lot of data to consider. If so, you should perhaps try to find features that do the best in predicting a random sample of the data rather than the entire dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a regression tool like Principle Component Analysis? PCA is used to determine which data variables best describe the outcome. This way, if you have 18 columns, PCA can pick out the top 5 variables (for example) which can best predict your model outcome. This saves you looping through all the different combinations like you are currently doing.

Comment: The problem with PCA in this context is that it essentially creates composite features that are linear combinations of the existing features, so it doesn't directly help with selecting certain features to be considered to the exclusion of others. You could perhaps look at the coefficients in the linear combination to decide which features play a larger role, but note that this isn't the usual workflow with PCA.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, I'm not really an experts in this field. But I do believe that you could check the first two principal component and select those  features that have higher weights? It is this what you mean in your comment?

Comment: @Lucas Right, higher in absolute value, that is; that's what I meant by "look at the coefficients in the linear combination...". Alternatively, you could use the absolute values to form a probability distribution by which to select features; doing this leads to one version of the [CUR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUR_matrix_approximation).

Comment: @BenGrossmann, thanks a lot for the feedback, really apprecite it